# ¿Cómo agregar un marcador (Marker) dinamicamente en un mapa de Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo un div dividido en dos partes, uno con una lista de resultados y la otra con un mapa que contiene varios marcadores (Markers) situados en dicho mapa, cada uno de esos marcadores corresponde a un resultado, esos datos los leo desde un JSON.

Ahora requiero que al hacer mouseover sobre cada resultado, se muestre en el mapa un nuevo marcador (de otro color) para conocer la ubicación de ese resultado (Inmueble) en el mapa.

Ya tengo la funcionalidad de mouseover funcionando y recibo en el script las coordenadas, lo que no sé es como hacer para mostrar el nuevo marcador.

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 6.330313,
      lng: -75.557731
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  getLocations()
}


const getLocations = () => {
  fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(locations => {
      let locationsInfo = []

      locations.forEach(location => {
        let locationData = {
          position: {
            lat: location.punto.coordinates[1],
            lng: location.punto.coordinates[0]
          },
         name: location.nombre_sede
        }
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)
      })

      dibujarMapa(locationsInfo)
    })
}

const dibujarMapa = (locationsInfo) => {

  map.setCenter(locationsInfo[0].position); 

  let markers = locationsInfo.map(place => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: place.position,
      map: map,
      title: place.name
    })
  })
}
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Livewire.hook('message.processed', (el, component) => {
        
        let lat = @this.lat

        let lng = @this.lng

        const image =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";

        var actualMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
            icon: image,
            map: map,
        });
    })  
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya estás ubicando markers, usando `google.maps.Marker` pasando como parámetro `map`, que es una instancia de `google.maps.Map`. Según entiendo, el problema surgiría porque el objeto de la clase `google.maps.Map` está inaccesible, porque está dentro de una función. Para solucionar esto hay dos opciones, o pones los eventos y la creación de markers dentro de la función `dibujarMapa` o sacas afuera la creación del mapa, esta última opción es la mas escalable y ordenada. Aquí un ejemplo:

```js
let map; //<--- Esta es una referencia global al objeto de google.maps.Map

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 6.330313,
      lng: -75.557731
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  getLocations() // <-- Usamos este `onload` en lugar de uno propio
}


const getLocations = () => {
  fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(locations => {
      let locationsInfo = []

      locations.forEach(location => {
        let locationData = {
          position: {
            lat: location.punto.coordinates[1],
            lng: location.punto.coordinates[0]
          },
          name: location.nombre_sede
        }
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)
      })

      dibujarMapa(locationsInfo)
    })
}

const dibujarMapa = (locationsInfo) => {

  map.setCenter(locationsInfo[0].position); //<-- volvemos a centrar el mapa

  let markers = locationsInfo.map(place => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: place.position,
      map: map, //<-- este map es el definido arriba, y es fundamental para ande todo
      title: place.name
    })
  })
}


// Aquí ponemos los markers usando el "map" definido mas arriba
```

Haciendolo de esta manera, siempre tienes acceso a `map`, desde cualquier función. Otro detalle sería usar el `onload` de la api y no uno propio, solo para no tener dos onloads, nada mas.
Creando el mapa afuera, puedes volverlo a centrar cuando quieras con `.setCenter`.

Los momentos en los que se cargan todos los elementos los puedes cambiar, siempre teniendo presente que antes de agregar markers el mapa debe estar cargado y además el mapa idelmente tendría que poder ser accesible de cualquier lugar, es decir no definido por ejemplo dentro de una función.

Comment: Hola Emeeus, muchas gracias! funciona como lo requiero, ahora tengo otra dudaspost respuesta... No quiero que se quede el marcador despues del mouseover, que sea temporal, solo se muestre el actual.

Comment: En ese caso, cada marker deberías ponerlo en un array, pero en lugar de map, null como parámetro.   Luego vas habilitando y deshabilitando cada marker en función de cual está onmouseover.  Ejemplo: `markers[0].setMap(null)` para deshabilitar el primero, `marker[1].setMap(map)` para habilitar el segundo. En cada mouseover deberías deshabilitar todos y habilitar el que esté over.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con tu respuesta, y agregué al final mi script. Intenté varias cosas con la info que me diste y la documentación y no lo he logrado. No entiendo muy bien como se está guardando la información en el mapa, yo cree una variable llamada `actualMarker` dibujo el nuevo marker sobre los anteriores, entonces debería ser el primero (En este método) el que se dibuja, se muestra el ícon, paso el mouse sobre otro resultado, se debería mostrar solo el segundo, pero muestra el anterior también, entonces como puedo borrar el anterior?

Comment: Yo agregué la función `markers.push(marker);` en `var market` pero cuando hago `console.log(markers)` el array está vacío, si hago `markers.push(actualMarker);` en `var actualMarker` si guarda el elemento en el array, pero no tiene sentido porque ya está dibujado el marcador y si vacío el array, continúa el marker en el mapa.

Comment: La formulación de la pregunta ahora no quedó clara, yo te recomendaría que hagas hagas un ejémplo mínimo, quizá con un mínimo html que exponga el problema para que lo podamos reproducir. Cuando te recomiendo guardar los markers me refiero a guardar las instancias de `google.maps.Marker` creadas, poniendo como map `null` en una primera instancia.